# Firefox Issue- Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session

Tags: exception, selenium-webdriver, firefox, firefox-driver

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
        FirefoxOptions option= new FirefoxOptions();
        option.merge(capabilities);
        WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(option);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
```

I am getting this error

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:565)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:242)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:157)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:110)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:98)
at com.app.selenium.OpenBrowser.main(OpenBrowser.java:27)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Driver server process died prematurely.
Build info: version: '4.4.0', revision: 'e5c75ed026a'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:226)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:98)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:547)
... 5 more

Code for instantiating firefox, i have tried everything but i keep getting this error, Not able to open Firefox through selenium
Firefox version- 112.0.1

I am facing issue with only firefox, chrome and edge are working

Answer (score 0):

issue resolved it was a compatibility issue.
i had to give driverVersion in webdriver manager as latest firefox driver was not compatible with the browser i installed

Comment: You can mark your own answer as accepted.